# Clipped layer area dont get uniform shadow in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, mask, layer-style, blending

See the problem below, **Blue layer is clipped with the grey background** but as soon the blue shape layer starts *"Shadow Intensity is low"*

[image]

Here is a closeup of the problem
[image]

Okay here is the Layer Panel for this
[image]

Comment: Showing the layers panel would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an optical illusion - if you zoom in really close, you'll notice that the shadow is actually the same, but because of the higher contrast between the white part and the shadow, it seems to have a contour that the blue part does not (at least that's what it looks like for me).

What you can do (it's a bit of a workaround, I know) is:

1. Apply a Stroke to the white part of the rectangle (I'm assuming that the blue layer is the Clipping Mask, not the other way around).
2. Group *only* the white layer.
3. Apply the Drop Shadow to the group.
4. Make the blue layer a Clipping Mask (it needs to be directly above the group). The result should be similar to this:

[image: After applying Stroke.]

If you zoom in, you will see that the white part is now smaller (with the stroke *inside* the shape), but you get the impression that the shadow is more even.

Hope this helps, even if a little!

Comment: I am using Blue layer on top, but i think that it is a kind of optical illusion or is it my LED screen which shows different shadow as i move the screen up and down

Answer (score 0):

The blue color is getting merged with the shadow effect. Try to change the **contour** from the **drop shadow wizard**[image: It will work for me]